# How can I write a loop that divides the operand by 2 each time?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have this for loop in C:

```
for (x=100;x>=3.0;x/=2){......}
```

I am trying to write an equivalent `for` loop in MATLAB. I have tried this one

```
for x=100:/2:3
```

but this doesn't give any results. So my problem is how to dividing by 2 in each step.

Comment: you mean matlab and not mathlab, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use while instead:

```
x = 100;
while ( x >= 3.0)
  ...
  x = x / 2;
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code:

```
div = 100./power(2,0:100);
div(div<3) = [];

for i=div
    disp(i);
end
```

However, in case you want to round each time (I don't know whether you used **int** or **double**), it won't work. You can use the *while* loop in that case, it is more appropriate.